# BT Mouse disconnects after upgrade to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, mouse, bluetooth

After upgrade to KUbuntu 12.04 my BT Mouse disconnects after some time not using it. This may be normal, but when I am back to my Notebook and want to proceed work, it does not reconnect. Befor upgrading it either did not disconnect or it did and reconnected without my notice. I read already there could be some sort of timeout (maybe energy saving) but I did not find a solution. Till now I have to press the small Button on my Mouse bottom side (named "Connect") and second I have to press the connect button in the BT Applet in Kubuntu, (named "Blue Devil"). Quite annoying... Any hints ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with a HP625-Laptop.

In the System-Log you can see the following:

```
...kernel....[....] usb 5-4: USB disconnect, device number 21
...kernel....[....] Bluetooth: hci0 urb ffff880089af0480 submission failed
...bluetoothd[992] Adapter /org/bluez/992/hci0 has been disabled
```

I think, that is a problem with the kernel.

---

The problem is solved:

1. De-Installing fglrx-Driver
2. De-Installing broadcom-sta-wlan-driver

After that everything works fine.
Now you can install the fglrx-Driver again.

The kernel supports the broadcom wlan- and blutetooth-device!