# Bluetooth mouse lags and eventually disconnects

Tags: mouse, bluetooth

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10.  I have a bluetooth mouse (Adesso iMouse S100).  Initially, the mouse works fine, but after a few minutes, it starts to lag a lot and it eventually disconnects.  And then, it takes forever to reconnect.

The mouse works fine on my win-7 issue (dual boot win-7/ubuntu).  So I know it's not an hardware issue

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: same issue here with a magic mouse on macbook pro. worked fine on 13.04. my problem is that the mouse is lagging and jumping a lot. unusable.

Comment: Did you try new batteries in the mouse?

Comment: @ubfan1 I'll, Ubuntu claims the mouse battery is 87% which seems fine, and since it worked before I upgraded. Currently I don't have new batteries available, but I must do a test.

Comment: try having a look here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsBluetoothUsbAdapters

Comment: @ubfan1 not a battery issue =/ just bought new batteries. This is a bug on saucy... my magic mouse just lagged and disconnected.

Comment: Have you tried the solutions here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/286112/bluetooth-loses-connection-with-mouse-in-13-04/345871#345871 and here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/131884/bt-mouse-disconnects-after-upgrade-to-12-04

Comment: I have this mouse as well, It disconnects from windows 7 after a few seconds of inactivity, behaves the same on Linux but reconnects a bit faster. It's a fine mouse but it being disconnecting like that and takes 5 seconds or more to reconnect annoys me.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an USB problem to me. Here is what you might try : **A) Install a different kernel** or **B) Build you own kernel**.

.

**A) Install a different kernel**, not build FOR Ubuntu. Cannonical may have done some mistakes on their kernels. Current Ubuntu 13.10's kernel is `3.11` but you can download recent version (today it's 13.12 the latest stable version) on `http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/` .

Choose the 2 packages for your architecture (64 bits = amd64, 32 bits = i386) and install them in this order : *linux-image-XXX* first, then *linux-header-XXX* second. 
You can install the .deb packages with *gdebi* (`sudo apt-get install gdebi`) with visual interface by double-click on the .deb file, or you can use these commandline :

```
cd path/to/file
```

(replace *path/to/file* by the directory containing the .deb packages, default is *~/Downloads*)

```
sudo dpkg -i package_to_install
```

(replace *package_to_install* by the name of the .deb file you want to install, here it should be something like *linux-image-XXX-amd64.deb*)

.

**B) Build you own kernel** with a modified `hid.h` value (usb2.0 driver), to allow the USB 2.0 to be more permissive. I used to do that until kernel 3.11 was out for my Perixx gaming mouse (wired mouse). This custom kernel is based on your system's current kernel, so it's guaranteed to be fully compatible with your Ubuntu. The steps are just below this paragraph.

See [What is HID_MAX_USAGES](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251207/what-is-hid-max-usages) for knowing a little more about HID.H and why recompiling kernel can be a solution for your bluetooth mouse.

---

**Building a new kernel with modifier *hid.h* value :**

**1) Open a terminal** (**ctrl-alt-T**)

**2) Launch the command :**

- `sudo apt-get install fakeroot kernel-wedge build-essential makedumpfile kernel-package libncurses5 libncurses5-dev`

It installs the requiered packages for the kernel building. You can `apt-get remove <packages>` afterwards to uninstall them if you wish.

**3) Enter the following commands to create a directory for the kernel sources :**

- `mkdir ~/source`
- `cd ~/source`
- `apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)`

**4) Type :**

- `cd linux`

Press **Tab** to auto-fill the name, then press **Enter**.

**5) Launch :**

- `gedit include/linux/hid.h`

Find (**Ctrl + F**) the line `#define HID_MAX_USAGES` and change it's value to `'64000'`.

**6) Launch :**

```
cp -vi /boot/config-`uname -r` .config
```

To copy the configuration file of your current system.

**7) (*Optionnal*) To speed up the building process, you can adjust the *concurrency level*. Launch :**

- `export CONCURRENCY_LEVEL=#`

Replace `#` by the number of your CPU's cores + 1 (Dual-core will be "3", Quad-core "5", …)

**8) Launch :**

- `make-kpkg clean`

To prepare the directory needed by the building process.

**9) Launch** :

- `fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version=-sk kernel-image kernel-headers`

This will start the kernel building process. It can take a while (between 1h and 8h following your hardware). If the process is interrupted for some reason, you should launch the command `rm ~/source` and start over from step 3. The kernel binaries *.deb* will be placed in *~/source*.

---

**To install the new kernel :**

**1) Open nautilus (file explorer) and go to */lib/modules*.**

**2) Open a Terminal and launch :**

- `cd ~/source`

**3) Type the following commands and press **Tab** to auto-fill the version of kernel, named here (KERNEL_VERSION) :**

- `sudo dpkg -i linux-image-`
- `sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-`

Both commands (once filled by **Tab**) must end by *.deb*

**4) Launch :**

- `sudo update-initramfs -c -k KERNEL_NAME`

You have to replace KERNEL_NAME by the name used by the directory containing the modifier kernel (should end with "-sk" in nautilus).

**5) Launch :**

- `sudo update-grub`

(and also `sudo update-burg` if you use BURG).

**6) Restart the computer.**

You now run a custom kernel ! Congrats'

---

If that doesn't work, the problem is NOT caused by HID (usb2.0 driver) and I have no idea how to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

This also looks like a "Pooling" problem to me..
I found a similar problem, but only during gaming in ubuntu 12.04 on steam..!!
Might be associated...might be not.

If you feel the lagging might be due to pooling interval you can decrease it..by the following, (basically its similar to what has already been suggested, use a new kernel)

Try the following resource ..
http://wiki.quakeworld.nu/Howto_customise_mouse_polling_rate